# Using Sed or awk to put a string at the end of a line

Tags: sed

I am trying to place a different sting at the end of each line using. The below works but not when the file is large. x=line # in the file. The data goes to the end with $.

Let data=0
Let x=0 
while [ $data -lt 10 ] 
do 
data=$(($data+1))

x=$(($x+11))

sed  -i  ''"$x"'s/$/ '"$data"' /' file
.
done

What I am trying to do.

Before:file_name

abc abc abc 
abc abc abc 
abc abc abc

After:file_name 
abc abc abc 1 
abc abc abc 2 
abc abc abc 3 
etc...

Answer (score 0):

You just need this:

```
sed -i 's/$/ '"$data"'/' filename
```

The regular expression `$` matches at the end of the line.

Note, to substitute the value of a variable, you don't need to `echo` it.

Comment: Each line will have a different value, How do I reference each line?. Thank you.

Comment: This seems to work. sed  -i ''"$x"'s/$/ '"$data"' /' test_data..                    . Just need a push in the right   Thanks Glen .

Comment: Trying using sed  -i ''"$x"'s/$/ '"$data"' /' filename getting weird out put \r

Comment: Are you saying that `$data` is different for each line?

Comment: @josephrob, calling `sed` for each line of a file is highly inefficient. Please explain (up in your question) what you are actually trying to accomplish. [#XYproblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/7552)

Comment: In a nut shell. I have 6 columns of data. I pick a data value from column 2 row one, call the initial position x=2,y=1. I do a lookup at  the data in that position and place the result in a new column call it x=7. This continues until all the values of y are checked.

Comment: You might want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -- afterwards, edit your question to provide sample data.'

Comment: Oh, I think I get it. You probably want `awk '{$7 = $2; print}' file`

Comment: The column 7 data position for each row is different. I've modified my question to clarify. I am using bash. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sorry, you have not increased the clarity of your question in any way.

Comment: Ummm let me try harder. File has x lines. I am adding a new data value at the end of each line.

Comment: all you need to do is show 3 or 4 lines of actual numbers, and then show what your desired output would be. No "x", no "abc", no "$data"

Comment: Changed question to clarify.

Comment: @josephrob: No, you haven't.  If you take the second word from the first line, you have `abc`.  How do you get from there to appending a `1` to line 1 (where, BTW, it becomes column 4)?  What do you mean when you say "x=7"?  You say "... until all the values of *y* are checked."  Do you mean "... until all the lines are checked."?  If so, why not just say "... until all the lines are checked."?  Etc...  It looks like you are just trying to number the lines of the file, similar to `cat -n` or the `nl` command, but with the numbers at the end.  If that's it, say so.  And maybe say why.

Comment: As simple as I can put it. Say you have a file with one column. You want to add a 2nd column row value pending on the value in the 1st column row. This works fine "sed -i ''"$x"'s/$/ '"$data"' /' file" for putting the data in the 2nd column row but not when I run it against a large data set. Thanks for all the help.